# viewDidAppear Not Firing in Tabbarcontroller>NavigationController>UITableView

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidappear

I currently have a tab bar controller set up with a navigationcontroller on one of the tabs, then I have a UITableView nib set up for that Navigationcontrollers view. All of this has been set up through IB and I want to keep it that way. Kind of like this tutorial http://twilloapp.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-embed-navigation-controller.html
 now the view loads perfectly when ViewDidLoad is called. But when I then load further views via code IE

```
MyApp_AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)delegate.controller.selectedViewController;

newViewController = [[newViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newView" bundle:nil];

[nav pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];

//At this point the view works! and loads
```

If I try to go back with the navigation toolbar it goes back to my previous view fine
Now I need to refresh the tableview when I go back but calling `viewDidAppear` does not work.

I tried adding `UINavigationDelegate` to the same `ViewController` Class as  the tableview and then calling `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:`

But that did not work. I also tried adding the same delegate as the tab bar controller and adding the same `navigationController didShowViewController:` there but that also failed.

How do I get this table to refresh every time the view loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found  I was missing the Delegate declaration in the Interface file. doh!  also I tried that in lots of places it only ended up working when I added it to the NavigationControllers first view (my table view)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to call `viewDidAppear` from your code.  Cocoa Touch should do that for you.

Call the table view's `reloadData` method to get it to refresh its contents.

Comment: Yes but where do I call that? That needs to go in viewwillAppear or viewDidAppear so that when the view controlelr appears it refreshes the table